# Three20 integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

I am new for iPhone application development. I want to make an photo album application. But I don't know how to show images like slideshow in iPhone. After searching on internet I got an information about three20 open framework. So I want to know about how should I start with three20. I also downloaded the facebook source from `github`.
I also got some information that if we use some private API of three20 then our app won't be accepted for apple store.
so please guide me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Apple referred indirectly to the three20 framework in their last Developer Conference and stated it is not necessary to use third party frameworks for photo viewer style scrolling applications. Three20 is fantastic coding, but is now outdated and solves a problem that has since been resolved by Apple's standard library code (e.g. photo scroller with zoom - Indeed Apple claim there was never a problem in the first place, but that there was insufficient documentation for developers to know how to do photo scrolling efficiently). Unless you want to implement the other specific three20 features you are best off avoiding using it. Check out the developer conference videos on advanced scroll views.

The most relevant video is from WWDC 2010 - assuming you have iOS dev center membership, you can check [**this**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/), which is the most relevant:

and look for the session `"Designing apps with Scroll Views"`

Also check [**this**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) one may be of interest:

and look for the video session `"Advanced ScrollView Techniques"`

Also check out the video on paged scrolling from WWDC 2012.

Comment: ok but then how I can start of making slidshow type application,I mean is there any other tools provided from apple itself or not?

Comment: For that I think you will find the paged scrolling video from WWDC 2012 video will help. Also check out collection views and advanced collection views if you need more flexibility. They are very powerful and there is a slide viewer type example somewhere in the sample code. I can't find it again now at a quick glance, so you will need to do a little digging to find it.